# how to change date format on this html user form

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, date-formatting

I have the html form which enter data into mysql DB, but in input field of date it has this format,

```
(mm/dd/yyyy)
```

BUT I prefer to use this format on entering date

```
(dd/mm/yyyy)
```

Can any body help to change the format.

Here the HTML form

```
<html>
 <head>
```

```
  <body><p>Admition number:<br>
   <input type="text" class="idNum" id="idnumber"    
   onkeyup="javascript:capitalize(this.id,   
   this.value);" name="idnumber" size="20">
   <br />
   Former school:<br>
   <input type="text" id="former_school" onkeyup="javascript:capitalize(this.id,     
   this.value);"         
   name="former_school" size="20">
  <br>
   Name of Child:<br>
   <input class="fname" type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="javascript:capitalize(this.id,   
   this.value);" name="fname" size="20">
   <br />
   Admission date:<br>                                        
   <input type="date" id="add_date" placeholder="date-month-year" name="add_date"    
   size="20">
   <br />
   Nationality:<br>
   <input type="text" id="country" onkeyup="javascript:capitalize(this.id,   
   this.value);"           
   name="country" size="20">
  <br />
  Date of Birth:<br>                
  <input type="date" id="date"  placeholder="date-month-year" name="date" size="20">
  <br />
  Tribe:<br>
  <input type="text" id="tribe" onkeyup="javascript:capitalize(this.id, this.value);"      
   name="tribe" size="20">
   </body>
  </html>
```

This is php code for inserting data, NOTE: not the same with field above(html) becose i just mention few fields from html page.

```
 <?php 
  include("Connections/conn.php")?>

  <?php
  $idnumber=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idnumber']);
  $insert="INSERT INTO     
  student(idnumber,former_school,fname,add_date,country,date,tribe)   
  VALUES('".$_POST["idnumber"]."','".$_POST["former_school"]."',
  '".$_POST["fname"]."','".$_POST["add_date"]."','".$_POST["country"]."',
   '".$_POST["date"]."','".$_POST["tribe"]."')";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing your dates as actual *dates* and not strings. You're only making your life more difficult by storing them in a non-standard format.

But if you insist on using this format, this code will work for you:

```
$original = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '04/18/1973');
$date     = $original->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Where shoud I put this scipts?

Comment: In the portion of code that handles your form submissions and before you insert that data into the database.

Comment: It gives me this erroy ( Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\db_ Bahari_V4\insert_std.php on line 5)

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: the version of php is 5.4.16

Comment: What date are you using in your test?

Comment: this mm/dd/yyyy BUT I prefer this dd/mm/yyyy(22/12/2013)

Comment: @msuya The arguments to `DateTime::createFromFormat` were in the wrong order. I've fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

`<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> <table> <tr> <th>Posted on: </th> <td>
<?php $date = '{{posted}}';</td> </tr> </table> </script> echo date('d M Y',strtotime($date));?>`

Comment: What question has this answered?  The table markup you use isn't mentioned anywhere else.